# Setting display:none to cell on first row messes up table layout

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following example table-based grid layout that I'm having trouble with:
http://jsfiddle.net/ccfa6kvb/1/

Basically my problem is that if I hide the gap cell on the first row, the rest of my gap column expands and messes up the layout. You can try this via the Toggle button I provided.

The cell is being initially generated with `display:none`, but has both `width` and `min-width` set to it, just as the other ones in my column.

What I see in the debugger is that somehow the third cell takes its place and calls out the shots on what width to set on the second column.

Can someone please explain why this happens? Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`display: none` will take an element completely out of the document's render flow, causing adjacent elements affected by that hidden element to re-layout accordingly. It doesn't matter what other properties are set to when `display: none` is applied which is why your `width` and `min-width` values don't have any visible affect.

You probably want `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`. This will render the element invisible but keep its place within the document's layout.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I thought as much. I also tried adding a fake header to dictate the column widths, but that hasn't worked either.
Might have to call quits on this approach and look for a new one. The `visibility:hidden` would work, yes, but it's not the intended approach for my task, which deals with hiding adjacent gaps when something is made invisible.

Will also accept the answer. Cheers!