# HTML Table search on each column Individually using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with 5 columns. the following code will filter the data on basis of all columns. I want to filter the data for each column. for ex: if there are 10 columns then 10 search fields and Also how can I make HTML part Dynamic so that I don't have to add one more search text field whenever a new column is added.

```
<input id="myInput" type="text"  />

<script>
   function filterTable(event) {
    var filter = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
    var rows = document.querySelector("#myTable tbody").rows;

    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var Col1 = rows[i].cells[0].textContent.toUpperCase();
        var Col2 = rows[i].cells[1].textContent.toUpperCase();
        var Col3 = rows[i].cells[2].textContent.toUpperCase();
        var Col4 = rows[i].cells[3].textContent.toUpperCase();
        var Col5 = rows[i].cells[4].textContent.toUpperCase();
        if (Col1.indexOf(filter) > -1 || Col2.indexOf(filter) > -1 || Col3.indexOf(filter) > -1
          || Col4.indexOf(filter) > -1 || Col5.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            rows[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            rows[i].style.display = "none";
        }      
    }
}

document.querySelector(''#myInput'').addEventListener(''keyup'', filterTable, false);
</script>
```

I want to have this kind of functionality:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the rows and then the columns. The `Array.from` method allows you to cast an element list to an array so that you can iterate over the children with `Array.prototype.forEach`.

All you need to do is have a `show` initialized to `true` for each row. Then if any DOES NOT column meets the filter criteria, you set show to `false`. After looping through all columns you display the row based on the final value of `show`.

**Edit:** Make sure you are using a browser that supports ES6+. There is a polyfill available for [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill) on the MDN site.

```js
function filterTable(event) {
  let filter = event.target.value.trim().toLowerCase();
  let rows = document.querySelector('#myTable tbody').rows;
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    let row = rows[i], show = false;
    if (filter.length > 0) {
      for (let j = 0; j < row.children.length; j++) {
        let col = row.children[j], text = col.textContent.toLowerCase();
        if (text.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          show = true;
          continue;
        }
      }
    } else {
      show = true;
    }
    // Avoid using 'row.styledisplay' - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28028656/1762224
    // Avoid using 'row.visibility'   - rows do not collapse
    toggleClass(row, 'hidden-row', !show);
  }
}

function toggleClass(el, className, state) {
  if (el.classList) el.classList.toggle(className, state);
  else {
    var classes = el.className.split(' ');
    var existingIndex = classes.indexOf(className);
    if (state === undefined) {
      if (existingIndex > -1) classes.splice(existingIndex, 1)
      else classes.push(existingIndex);
    } else {
      if (!state) classes.splice(existingIndex, 1)
      else classes.push(existingIndex);
    }
    el.className = classes.join(' ');
  }
}

document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('keyup', filterTable, false);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 8px;
}
.field label {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
}
#myTable {
  margin-top: 0.667em;
  width: 100%;
}
#myTable th {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.hidden-row {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="field"><label for="myInput">Filter:</label><input id="myInput" type="text" /></div>
<table id="myTable" class="pure-table pure-table-horizontal">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>drink</th>
      <th>pizza</th>
      <th>movie</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Homer</td>
      <td>Squishie</td>
      <td>Magheritta</td>
      <td>The Avengers</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Marge</td>
      <td>Squishie</td>
      <td>Magheritta</td>
      <td>The Avengers</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bart</td>
      <td>Squishie</td>
      <td>Pepperoni</td>
      <td>Black Dynamite</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lisa</td>
      <td>Buzz Cola</td>
      <td>Pepperoni</td>
      <td>Iron Man</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maggie</td>
      <td>Duff Beer</td>
      <td>Magheritta</td>
      <td>The Avengers</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kent</td>
      <td>Duff Beer</td>
      <td>Hawaiian</td>
      <td>The Avengers</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

### Search fields example

```js
populateTable(document.getElementById('simpsons'), getData());

function dataFields(data) {
  return data.reduce((r, x) => Object.keys(x).reduce((s, k) => s.indexOf(k) === -1 ? s.concat(k) : s, r), []);
}

/* Can be useful if working with raw JSON data */
function searchCriteria(fields) {
  return Array.from(fields).reduce((o, field) => {
    return Object.assign(o, { [field.getAttribute('placeholder')] : field.value });
  }, {});
}

function onFilter(e) {
  let table = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
  let fields = table.querySelectorAll('thead tr th input');
  let criteria = searchCriteria(fields); // Unused, but useful if filtering bindable data
  let searchText = Array.from(fields).map(field => field.value.trim());
  Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')).forEach(row => {
    let hideRow = false;
    Array.from(row.children).forEach((col, index) => {
      var value = col.innerHTML.trim().toLowerCase();
      var search = searchText[index].toLowerCase();
      if (search.length > 0) {
        if (!value.startsWith(search)) { /* or value.indexOf(search) === -1 */
          hideRow = true;
          return;
        }
      }
    });
    row.classList.toggle('hidden-row', hideRow);
  });
}

function populateTable(table, data) {
  let fields = dataFields(data);
  let thead = document.createElement('THEAD');
  let tr = document.createElement('TR');
  fields.forEach(field => {
    let th = document.createElement('TH');
    th.innerHTML = field;
    tr.appendChild(th);
  });
  thead.appendChild(tr);
  let tbody = document.createElement('TBODY');
  tr = document.createElement('TR');
  fields.forEach(field => {
    let th = document.createElement('TH');
    let input = document.createElement('INPUT');
    input.setAttribute('placeholder', field);
    input.addEventListener('keyup', onFilter);
    th.append(input);
    tr.appendChild(th);
  });
  thead.appendChild(tr);
  data.forEach(record => {
    let tr = document.createElement('TR');
    fields.forEach(field => {
      let td = document.createElement('TD');
      td.innerHTML = record[field];
      tr.appendChild(td);
    });
    tbody.append(tr);
  });
  table.appendChild(thead);
  table.appendChild(tbody);
}

function getData() {
  return [{
    "name": "Homer",
    "drink": "Squishie",
    "pizza": "Magheritta",
    "movie": "The Avengers"
  }, {
    "name": "Marge",
    "drink": "Squishie",
    "pizza": "Magheritta",
    "movie": "The Avengers"
  }, {
    "name": "Bart",
    "drink": "Squishie",
    "pizza": "Pepperoni",
    "movie": "Black Dynamite"
  }, {
    "name": "Lisa",
    "drink": "Buzz Cola",
    "pizza": "Pepperoni",
    "movie": "Iron Man"
  }, {
    "name": "Maggie",
    "drink": "Duff Beer",
    "pizza": "Magheritta",
    "movie": "The Avengers"
  }, {
    "name": "Kent",
    "drink": "Duff Beer",
    "pizza": "Hawaiian",
    "movie": "The Avengers"
  }];
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
table thead tr th {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
table thead tr:last-child {
  background: #eaeaea;
  border-bottom: 4px double #cbcbcb;
}
table thead tr th input {
  width: 100%;
}
table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
table tbody tr.hidden-row {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table id="simpsons" class="pure-table pure-table-horizontal"></table>
```

---

### Browser Compatibility

```
function onFilter(e) {
  var table = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
  console.log(table);
  var fields = table.querySelectorAll('thead tr th input');
  console.log(fields);
  var searchText = Array.from(fields).map(function (field) {
    return field.value.trim();
  });
  console.log(searchText);
  Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')).forEach(function (row) {
    var hideRow = false;
    Array.from(row.children).forEach(function (col, index) {
      var value = col.innerHTML.trim().toLowerCase();
      console.log(value);
      var search = searchText[index].toLowerCase();
      console.log(search);
      if (search.length > 0) {
        if (value.indexOf(search) === -1) {
          hideRow = true;
          return;
        }
      }
    });
    row.classList.toggle('hidden-row', hideRow);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Could you please revisit the Question. I've updated it with the desired output screenshot.

Comment: @steve I implemented an example for searching rows.

Comment: @steve You can use `value.indexOf(search) === -1` to test that the search does not exist "within" the value.

Comment: I have changed the code but still, not supporting is there any alternate for the array.from foreach ... please see the edited code

Comment: @steve If you are using IE, you will have to loop over the children the old-fashioned way by using a for loop and indexing through the children. You should be able to do this fairly easily. I can revisit this later. You could also convert this to jQuery.

Comment: @steve Updated the first example. You can adapt this with the second one to get the desired result.

Comment: @mr-polywhirl Thank you so much...life saver

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is iterate the .cells array with a for loop:

For this example, I used a variable to determine if the row should be shown.

```js
function filterTable(event) {
  var filter = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
  var rows = document.querySelector("#myTable tbody").rows;

  for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    // Placeholder to indicate if a row matches the given query.
    var shouldShowRow = false;
    // Loop over all the cells in this row.
    for (var k = 0; k < rows[i].cells.length) {
      // Check to see if this cell in this row matches the query.
      if (rows[i].cells[k].textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        // Yes, this cell matches, therefore this entire row matches.
        // Flip the show row boolean to indicate that we need to show.
        shouldShowRow = true;
        // Because this cell matches, we do not need to check any more cells.
        break;
      }
    }
    // Change the display on the row if we need to.
    if (shouldShowRow) {
      rows[i].style.display = "";
    } else rows[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array.
First map `col` to an array `colArr` and than using some you can match you can match `filter` content with content of `cols` .

```
for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
  let colArr = new Array(5).fill(0).map((e,index)=> rows[i].cells[index].textContent.toUpperCase();) 
     if (colArr.some(e=> e.indexOf(filter) > -1 ) {
         rows[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          rows[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }) 
}
```